# Use RegEx in IQueryable LINQ to search string in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm looking for a way to search for data in a CosmosDB container using regular expression (RegEx).
e.g. when I have documents with a name like this in a container:

```
{
  name = "test"
},
{
  name = "test_1"
},
{
  name = "test_data_1"
}
```

and search for name: `test` or `test_<number>`, first and second document will be found.

I have a model like this:

```
public class TestObj
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and a method that searches for `TestObj` objects by name:

```
public async Task<List<TestObject>> GetManyByName(string searchName)
{
    var regex = new Regex($"^{searchName}_\\d$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    var options = new QueryRequestOptions {PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("partitionId")};

    var container = client.GetContainer("dbId", "containerId");
    var iterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<TestObject>(false, null, options)
        .Where(x => x.Name == searchName || regex.IsMatch(x.Name))
        .ToFeedIterator();

    var results = new List<TestObject>();
    while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var feedResponse = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
        if (feedResponse.Any())
            results.AddRange(feedResponse);
    }

    return results.ToList();
}
```

When I run this code, I get an exception like this:
`DocumentClientException with status code 0, message: Method 'IsMatch' is not supported., inner exception: null, and response headers: null`

It looks like that `regex.IsMatch(x.Name)` doesn't work with `IQueryable`. I also tried `Regex.IsMatch()` but got the same exception.

[CosmosDB supports RegEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/regexmatch), so I just assumed that it works in code.
Is there a way that I can use RegEx with `IQueryable`? or it's not supported in code at all?
If not supported at all, is there a different way to achieve my goal? I want to use LINQ but I'm happy to see solutions that don't.

Comment: Try to use `(bool)CosmosLinq.InvokeUserDefinedFunction("REGEXMATCH", x.Name, $"^{searchName}_\\d$")`. Not tested just analyzed library's source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, Cosmos DB supports regex matching. However, there is no `RegexMatch` within the [supported LINQ operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/linq-to-sql#supported-linq-operators). I also didn't find any query translator for `RegexMatch` in the [.NET SDK V3 source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3).

I think the easiest workaround would be to write a  SQL query. You'll have to invoke `GetItemQueryIterator` with the appropriate query instead of `GetItemLinqQueryable`.

```cs
var query = new QueryDefinition(
    @"SELECT * FROM c
    WHERE c.Name = @searchName OR RegexMatch(c.Name, @searchPattern, 'i')")
    .WithParameter("@searchName", searchName)
    .WithParameter("@searchPattern", $"^{searchName}_\\d$");

var iterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<TestObject>(query, null, options);
```

As an alternative solution, you can use [EF Core Azure Cosmos DB Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/), which should support `Regex.IsMatch` according to [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/functions#string-functions). But this approach will require more changes as you'll need to configure DbContext and use another APIs. And it may have some limitations.

As a hackish workaround, you can create a [UDF in Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/udfs) that proxies to `RegexMatch`. Then you can use [`CosmosLinq.InvokeUserDefinedFunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.linq.cosmoslinq.invokeuserdefinedfunction?view=azure-dotnet) in your LINQ code. But it's better to avoid UDFs if an equivalent system function exists. So I do not recommend this approach.

Comment: I just couldn't find the Supported LINQ operators document page and you gave me the link.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way around it as IQueryable is trying to execute a SQL query. You'll have either to force the "iterator" collection into an in-memory Enumerable, or call a stored procedure where you could apply the regular expression.